# How to stack buttons (grid layout) in a Revit Ribbon Panel

Tags: c#, ribbon, revit-api

I've created a custom panel that I've placed in the Revit `Modify` tab.  Currently, the buttons are placed strictly horizontally.  I would like to stack them in a grid format (rows and columns).  Does any know the way to access the layout properties or any other means of accomplishing this?

[image]

### Code:

```
var pSource = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonPanelSource()
{
    Title = sPanel,
    KeyTip = "P",
    Id = "autosprink_shr",
    IsSlideOutPanelVisible = true,
    Description = null,
    DialogLauncher = null,
    UID = null,
    Tag = null,
    Name = null
};

var hPanel = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonPanel()
{
    Id = sPanel,
    Source = pSource,
    IsVisible = true,
    IsEnabled = true, 
};

string sBtnText;

pIcon = Properties.Resources.AS_Revit_UI_SelectLike_icon.GetHbitmap();
sBtnText = "Select All Like";
var pPanelBtn = CreatePanelButton(pIcon, sBtnText, "id_asselectalllike", "", 32, 32, BUTTONSIZE.LARGE);
Autodesk.Windows.ComponentManager.UIElementActivated += SelectAllLikeBtn;
hPanel.Source.Items.Add(pPanelBtn);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  When you call the command to add the `RibbonItem` to the panel, you should instead call `RibbonPanel.AddStackedItems();`.  You can pass in either two or three, and it will stack them into one "column".

Comment: Unfortunately, that falls under the `Autodesk.Revit.UI` namespace, and I'm working in the `Autodesk.Windows` namespace...

Comment: Use of the `Autodesk.Windows` namespace is not officially supported in Revit, afaik.

Comment: Is there something you want to do which makes using the Autodesk.Windows namespace necessary? Everything within your code above is available in the supported UI namespace...

Comment: The Revit _Modify_ tab is an `Autodesk.Windows` tab, so when I wanted to add a `Panel`, it had to be under the same namespace.  It wouldn't let me cast it or anything.  Kind of a pain.  You have to do a bunch of work.  It ended up working out though.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a bit of a struggle, I solved my problem (with some helpful suggestions for Mike and Jeremy ^^).  If you want to add your own Ribbon Panel to the Revit *Modify* tab in a grid layout like this, it's a bit work, but totally worth it!

[image]

First, create a function to add the `Panel` to the tab:

```
public Autodesk.Windows.RibbonPanel CreateCustomPanel()
{
    string sPanel = "Panel Name";
    IntPtr pIcon;

    var pSource = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonPanelSource()
    {
        Title = sPanel, 
        Id = "id_name", 
        IsSlideOutPanelVisible = true, 
        Description = null,
        DialogLauncher = null, 
        UID = null, 
        Tag = null, 
        Name = null,
    };

    var pRow1Source = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonSubPanelSource()
    {
        Description = null, Id = "row1_shr", Name = null, Tag = null, UID = null
    };
    var pRow2Source = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonSubPanelSource()
    {
        Description = null, Id = "row2_shr", Name = null, Tag = null, UID = null
    };

    var hPanel = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonPanel()
    {
        Source = pSource, IsVisible = true, IsEnabled = true
    };

    var hPanelRow1 = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonRowPanel()
    {
        Height = 32, Id = "pRow1", IsEnabled = true, IsVisible = true, Source = pRow1Source
    };

    var hPanelRow2 = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonRowPanel()
    {
        Height = 32, Id = "pRow1", IsEnabled = true, IsVisible = true, Source = pRow2Source
    };

    Autodesk.Windows.RibbonSeparator pBreak = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonSeparator();
    pBreak.SeparatorStyle = Autodesk.Windows.RibbonSeparatorStyle.Invisible;

    string sBtnText;
    // Add buttons to Row 1
    pIcon = Properties.Resources.YourResourceName.GetHBitmap();
    sBtnText = "Button Text";
    var pPanelBtn = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonButton()
    {
        //SET BUTTON PROPERTIES HERE
    };
    Autodesk.Windows.ComponentManager.UIElementActivated += BtnEventHandler;
    hPanelRow1.Source.Items.Add(pPanelBtn);
    hPanelRow1.Source.Items.Add(pBreak);

    //Repeat for more buttons
    hPanel.Source.Items.Add(hPanelRow1);
    hPanel.Source.Items.Add(new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonRowBreak());
    //Repeat for second row
    hPanel.Source.Items.Add(hPanelRow2);

    return hPanel;
}
```

Then, it's as easy as:

```
Autodesk.Windows.RibbonControl pRibbon = Autodesk.Windows.ComponentManager.Ribbon;
foreach (var pTab in pRibbon.Tabs)
{
    if (pTab.Id == "Modify")
    {
        pTab.Panels.Add(CreateCustomPanel());
        break;
    }
}
```